# How do I display the validation which failed in my Rails unit test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

**Summary**: Failed unit tests tell me which assert (file:line) failed, but not which validation resulted in the failure.

**More info**: I have 11 validations in one of my models.  Unit testing is great, whether I run `rake test:units --trace` or `ruby -Itest test/unit/mymodel_test.rb`.  However, despite the fact that it tells me exactly which `assert` failed me, I am not told which validation failed.  I must be missing something obvious, because I can't ask Google this question well enough to get an answer.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that what you want is this:

```
assert person.valid?, person.errors.full_messages.inspect
```

if the person model is not valid, the error messages are printed out for you to see.

Comment: This was useful but does not take into account when full_messages is an array.  I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 4):

In order to print one or more failed validations, use a test like this:

```
  test "post with neither name nor title" do
    p = Post.new
    assert p.valid?, p.errors.full_messages.inspect
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always take a look at the object errors for the invalid attribute.

```
class Person
   validates_presence_of :name
end

person = Person.new
person.valid?  # => false

person.errors[:name]  # =>  "can't be blank"
person.errors.full_messages  # => ["Name can't be blank"]
```

Take a look at the [ActiveRecord::Errors](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html) docs for more info.

Comment: Thanks, Oshuma.  While this isn't exactly what I need, it did lead me to experimenting with the debugger for unit tests.